# How to add a custom class to simple_form f.association as: :radio_buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using a simple_form with a

```
f.association as: :radio_buttons
```

This generates a html structure like

```
div.control-group
  label.control-label
  div.controls
    label.radio
    input[type="checkbox"]
```

I can add specific custom classes to the control-label and to the input field, using label_html = ... or input_html = ...

I however would like to add a specific class to the label.radio

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use item_wrapper_class

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.association :comments, :as => :radio_buttons, :item_wrapper_class => 'test_class'
```